# Converting HSL to RGB

Tags: lua, rgb

This should take a set an HSL color code and print out its equivalent in RGB.
It should print out    97, 153, 194.
Instead it prints out 0.3808, 0.60153333333333, 0.7592.

```
function HSL(hue, saturation, lightness, alpha)
    if hue < 0 or hue > 360 then
        return 0, 0, 0, alpha
    end
    if saturation < 0 or saturation > 1 then
        return 0, 0, 0, alpha
    end
    if lightness < 0 or lightness > 1 then
        return 0, 0, 0, alpha
    end
    local chroma = (1 - math.abs(2 * lightness - 1)) * saturation
    local h = hue/60
    local x =(1 - math.abs(h % 2 - 1)) * chroma
    local r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
    if h < 1 then
        r,g,b=chroma,x,0
    elseif h < 2 then
        r,b,g=x,chroma,0
    elseif h < 3 then
        r,g,b=0,chroma,x
    elseif h < 4 then
        r,g,b=0,x,chroma
    elseif h < 5 then
        r,g,b=x,0,chroma
    else
        r,g,b=chroma,0,x
    end
    local m = lightness - chroma/2
    return r+m,g+m,b+m,alpha
end

print(HSL(205, .44, .57))
```

Comment: Your function definition accepts four arguments but you're only calling it with three. Is this intentional? Does it influence your program?

Comment: Maybe you should follow the [Wikipedia algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSL) more closely.

Comment: There is also an error in the clause where h < 2: it assigns to `r,b,g` but should be `r,g,b`

Answer (score 7):

Your function gives values in the range `0-1`; multiply by 256 to get it in the range `0-256`.

Comment: Rather, multiply by 255, or otherwise make sure 255 is the highest value.